# "this@" syntax for extension function

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to figure out how to refer to `this` inside of a `with` block.

```
inline fun A.foo(bar: B, crossinline block: B.() -> Unit) {
    with (bar) {
        this@A.doSomething() // compile error, "unresolved reference @A"
        block()
    }
}
```

Here is my workaround:

```
inline fun A.foo(bar: B, crossinline block: B.() -> Unit) {
    val self = this
    with (bar) {
        self.doSomething() // okay, but ugly
        block()
    }
}
```

Is there a better way, and why doesn't this work?

Comment: `this@foo.doSomething()`

Comment: Yup, that did it.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon If you post this as an answer, I will accept it, since you were first. If you don't respond in a reasonable time frame, I'll accept the other poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i try the code 
[image]

you can use this@foo to access A,or use let instead

```
inline fun Activity.foo(bar: Fragment) {
    bar.let {
        this.xxx
    }
}
```

Comment: As @Drawn already answered, `this@foo` is what I wanted. `Let` does not have the same semantics here. Both my `foo` and `bar` have a property with the same name, and Kotlin chooses the "wrong" one with `let`, unlike with `with`.

Comment: use let ，you can access A with this,b with it，so  it doesn't  confusion

Comment: As I already mentioned, `let` does not work the same here. I want to write `this@A.color = color`, but with `let` it's `it.color = this.color`, which I find too difficult to read.